# Print a text file from a line number to another after searching for the lines

Tags: sed, grep, lp

I want to print a text file from `X` line number to `Y` line number

The value of  `X` & `Y` is determined by searching for a specific line in the text file(in this case the page number)

I search for the line by the following command

```
echo -n |grep -nr "Page # 2" FileName.txt |cut -f1 -d: ; echo -n |grep -nr "Page # 3" FileName.txt |cut -f1 -d:
```

for which I get an out put

> 67
>
> 128

I want to feed this output to the command below

```
sed -n 'X,Yp' FileName.txt
```

But I get them as two different lines how can i feed it to the `sed` command

There after I want to feed the result of the above command to the `lp` command something like this...

```
sed -n 'X,Yp' FileName.txt | lp -dmyprinter
```

Can this be done without creating a file?

Comment: `sed '/Page # 2/,/Page # 3/!d' < FileName.txt`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Please add this as an answer...It worked perfectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for the 2 phases to find out the lines beforehand. Just do the whole thing with `sed`:

```
sed '/Page # 2/,/Page # 3/!d' < FileName.txt
```

Comment: Just a slight modification...What if I want start it three lines before the point where i find `Page # 2` string in the file...is it possible to get the three lines above the `Page # 2` as well....Unfortunately the string in the line above can be fixed so cannot ad as a search criteria...

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep the values with variables, something like this:

```
FROM_LINE=`echo -n |grep -nr "Page # 2" FileName.txt |cut -f1 -d: `
TO_LINE=`echo -n |grep -nr "Page # 3" FileName.txt |cut -f1 -d:`
```

and then use these variables with sed:

```
sed -en "${FROM_LINE},${TO_LINE}p" FILE
```